# Split and validate text that contains brackets, commas and integers

Tags: validation, c#-4.0, split, data-manipulation

How can i split text which contains only brackets, commas and 3 integers. For example:

```
{5,40,30}
```

I also want to validate that it looks like above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this using regex.

```
 var testString = "12,23,{23,23},23,{51,22,345}{{]}1123,{12,12,232,123}{{33,33,33}}";

 var regex = new Regex(@"{\d+,\d+,\d+}");
 var matches = regex.Matches(testString);
```

The output of the above test string after match is

`{51,22,345}` and `{33,33,33}`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a non regex solution using string methods and LINQ which i prefer:

```
string text = "{5,40,30}";
bool valid = text.StartsWith("{") && text.EndsWith("}");
int[] integers = {};

if (valid)
{
    integers = text.Trim('{', '}').Split(',')
        .Select(s => s.TryGetInt32())
        .Where(nullInt => nullInt.HasValue)
        .Select(nullInt => nullInt.Value)
        .ToArray();
    valid = integers.Length == 3;
}
```

using this handy extension method that i use in LINQ queries to get a `Nullabel<int>` from a `string`, so similar to `int.TryParse` but with an `int?`.

```
public static int? TryGetInt32(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
}
```

Comment: What shall I inculde for using in TryGetInt32()?

Comment: @Programmer: put it in an extension class which must be `static` and accessible. You find examples [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977.aspx)

Comment: I got an error about TryGetInt32- string doesn't contain a definition for 'TryGetInt32'

Comment: @Programmer: yes, because it's an extension method. The link i've provided in my last comment tells everything about it. The class must look like `public static class MyExtensions{ public static int? TryGetInt32(this string item)
{
    int i;
    bool success = int.TryParse(item, out i);
    return success ? (int?)i : (int?)null;
} }` and it must be accessible from the code where you want to use this extension method.